# Keep two console windows open for terminated console apps in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, ide

Using Eclipse Indigo I would like to keep two console windows open - with different content from different terminated apps.

I have the following scenario:

1. I run a Java console app, it terminates and has some output in the console window
2. I use the "Open Console" icon to create a new console view.
3. I run another app (a Python app via the PyDev plugin); it terminates.

After this, both console windows contain the *same* text (the output from the Python app). To make it clear: the run of the second app (the Python app) cleans *both* console windows and then writes its output in both windows

But obviously I want the 1st console to show the output of the terminated Java app and the 2nd console to show the Python app.

How can I achieve this?

Comment: I am aware that there are a few answered questions similar to mine on stackoverflow, but I cannot get it working for the output of _terminated_ apps.

Answer (score 6):

Select "Open Console" -> "New Console View" for new Console View.
With the drop down menu "Display Selected Console" you can choose from diffrent consoles.

To avoid that the console of terminated programs will be deleted go to "Window" -> "Preferences" -> "Run/Debug" -> "Launching" and set "Remove terminated launches ..." to false

Comment: Unfortunatley this tip does _not_ solve the problem: the Preference Setting "Remove terminated launches ..." refers to the _Debug view_, not to the _Console view_. So the conetnet in the Console view still gets removed when an old app has terminated and a new app gets launched.

Comment: I use it to view the output of my terminated application. When i run my application for about 5 times (all terminated) i can choose by "Display selected Console" from 5 terminated console outputs.

What do you mean with "Debug View"?

Comment: Well, I run two *different* applications in an alternating manner. In that case the run of the second app cleans *both* console windows and writes its output in both windows. (I have incorporated this clarification in the question.)

Comment: With my solution I can run 2 _different_ applications. And even if both were terminated i can choose by _Display selected Console_ from those.